# How do I reduce "else if" statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a way to reduce the "else if" statements? I have been tasked to make a program that will
ask the user to input 3 grades then determine the average of those numbers, and that would also
output the equivalent grade of the computed average based on the table that they have given.

here is my code so far.

```
if (ave >= 98){
    System.out.println("Your grade is 1!");
}
else if (ave >= 95){
    System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.25!");
}
else if (ave >= 92){
    System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.5!");
}   
else if (ave >= 89){
    System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.75!");
}
else if (ave >= 86){
    System.out.println ("Your grade is 2!");
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Why do you have multiple `if (ave >= 95)` conditions?

Comment: Why you need to reduce `if...else` statements?

Comment: Besides, do you have additional code that reads the 3 grades and computes the average (as required according to your description)?

Comment: think it was a typo when they were pasting their code in

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, Sorry I must have made a mistake while copy pasting the code from my program.

Comment: Ignore my answer, it was made before the edit. From your current code, while the grade output is confusing, I believe a string of else ifs may be the simplest way to solve this if you really want a unique output for each range

Comment: @Mipmoop I don't think you can't reduce the `if..else` further.

Comment: Use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement) statement.  Also, grade goes up as `ave` goes down?

Comment: does a 83 average make you have a 2.25 grade?

Comment: I see, I'm new to programming so I don't really know if there's a better alternative way to type my code. but based on your answers, I think I will just continue using else if statements. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Mipmoop just make sure to finish your `else-if`s with an `else` statement, otherwise you're good to go

Comment: @kepotx yes . in our grading system the lower the number is, the higher the grade. 1 being the highest and 5 the lowest

Comment: You could use a data structure to define your ranges and map them to the grade but that could be an overkill depending on the purpose.

Comment: @ Ryan Millares Okay Thankyou!

Comment: are the average between 0 and 100 ? does a 0 average and 25 average both give 5 ? Do you have a formula that give the final grade ? you should give us this information, so we can use it to compute the final grade, this is way better than having lot of if/else statements

Comment: Sorry if my post is too  vague but here's the formula

1.0 = 98 – 100 %, 
1.25 = 95 – 97 %, 
1.5 = 92 – 94 %, 
1.75 = 89 – 91 %, 
2.0 = 86 – 88 %, 
2.25 = 83 – 85 %, 
2.5 = 80 – 82 %, 
2.75 = 77 – 79 %, 
3.0 = 75 – 76 %, 
5.0 = Below 75 % average

Comment: @user16320675 ouch, i know.  i even included 'java' in the search but google thought better coz I haven't been there for ages. The second bit was just clarification - I have heard of golf.

Comment: @user16320675 a game where the lowest score is the winner

Comment: yah, i get it.  I'm just saying I understand the concept of a lower number being considered a higher placement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is smooth function (for each 3 point difference in `ave`, 0.25 points is added to grade), the grade value should be computed with regard to the minimum 86 and maximum 98 checked values:

```java
static double getGrade(int ave) {
    final int min = 86;
    double grade = 2.0;
    
    int p = (ave - min) / 3;
    p = p < 0 ? 0 : (p > 4 ? 4 : p); // acceptable ranges
    grade -= p * 0.25;
    
    System.out.println ("Your grade for ave = " + ave + " is " + grade + "!");
    return grade;
}
```

Tests:

```java
getGrade(99);
getGrade(94);
getGrade(86);
```

Output:

```
Your grade for ave = 99 is 1.0!
Your grade for ave = 94 is 1.5!
Your grade for ave = 86 is 2.0!
```

---

For the updated formula provided in the comments:

> 1.0 = 98 – 100 %, 1.25 = 95 – 97 %, 1.5 = 92 – 94 %, 1.75 = 89 – 91 %, 2.0 = 86 – 88 %, 2.25 = 83 – 85 %, 2.5 = 80 – 82 %, 2.75 = 77 – 79 %, 3.0 = 75 – 76 %, 5.0 = Below 75 % average

The code needs to be modified to provide values below 75 and between 75..77:

```java
static double getGrade(int ave) {
    double grade = 5.0;
    if (ave >= 75) {
        grade = 3.0;
        final int stepAve = 3;
        final int min = 77;
        final int ranges = 7;
        
        int p = ave < min ? -1 : (ave - min) / stepAve;
        p = p < 0 ? -1 : (p > ranges ? ranges : p); // acceptable ranges
        grade -= (p + 1) * 0.25;
    }
    
    System.out.println ("Your grade for ave = " + ave + " is " + grade + "!");
    return grade;
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (int i = 72; i < 100; i += 3) {
    getGrade(i);
}
```

Results:

```
Your grade for ave = 72 is 5.0!
Your grade for ave = 75 is 3.0!
Your grade for ave = 78 is 2.75!
Your grade for ave = 81 is 2.5!
Your grade for ave = 84 is 2.25!
Your grade for ave = 87 is 2.0!
Your grade for ave = 90 is 1.75!
Your grade for ave = 93 is 1.5!
Your grade for ave = 96 is 1.25!
Your grade for ave = 99 is 1.0!
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this you can extract the variables that changes, put them on a collection, and loop over the collection. In your case I would do something similar:

```
int[] threshold = new int[]{98,95,..};
String[] descr = new String[]{"1","1.25",..}

for(int i = 0; i < threshold.length; i++) {
    if(ave >= threshold[i]) {
        print("Your grade is " + descr[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `NavigableMap` to map the lower *average* to the grade.
Something like

```
/** Maps lower average to corresponding grade. */
static final NavigableMap<Integer, String> GRADES =
    Collections.unmodifiableNavigableMap( new TreeMap<>( Map.of(
        98, "1", 
        95, "1.25", 
        92, "1.5", 
        89, "1.75", 
        86, "2",
        Integer.MIN_VALUE, "not specified"    // avoid null check
    )));

String grade(int average) {
    return GRADES.floorEntry(average).getValue();
}
```

The last entry is just for the case that the average is less than 86, obviously it can be changed as needed. Also possible to have `Double`s instead of `String`s in the map.

Answer (score -1):

For multiple if..else if..else . it is always advisable to use switch statement.

```
public void DisplayGrade(int range)
{
    switch (range)
    {
        case  >= 98 :
          System.out.println ("Your grade is 1!");
        break;

        case >= 95:
           System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.25!");
        break;
        case  >= 92 :
           System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.5!");
        break; 
        case >= 89 :
           System.out.println ("Your grade is 1.75!");
        break;
        case >= 86:
           System.out.println ("Your grade is 2!");
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer to the question. It's more longer than the if else. Also, it will not compile with `case >= 89`

Comment: This code does not ever compile on Java 17 producing multiple errors like: `error: illegal start of expression case  >= 98 :`, `error: illegal start of expression case >= 95:`, etc.